# URL Rewriting with htaccess to replace question mark

Tags: .htaccess

The Structure of our URL is like the below , a sample link
36474_poem_Westron_Wind,_When_Wilt_Thou_Blow?.html

We would like to replace the ? with "", so basically whenever a URL of the above type is called, it should be automatically be redirected to
36474_poem_Westron_Wind,_When_Wilt_Thou_Blow.html

The Question mark can appear anywhere after "poem_" and before ".html"
Can you advise a structure to be used in .htaccess to get this redirection done?